# Download flac file for twitter videos?

Tags: python, audio, video, download, flac

I'm trying to download the flac file for twitter videos. Currently I'm able to download the mp4 for twitter videos and then convert them into flac files afterwards, however, this process takes a long time and I was curious if there was a workaround to download the flac files at the start so I don't have to convert them later on?

Comment: Does twitter provide flac encoded files?

Comment: After doing some researching, I discovered that as of now it's not possible to download just the flac file for Twitter videos.